# Proper way of checking "protected" types

Tags: python, types

In my code I try to check the type of returned value like so:

```
 resp = rt.rpc.get_ethernet_switching_table_information({'format': 'json'})
        if isinstance(resp, et._Element):
            resp = json.loads(resp.text)
```

put aside the reason I want to to this, I get a warning:

```
Access to a protected member _Element of a module
```

The code works of course, but i want it co be as clean as possible. How could I test the type of such variable in the most pythonic way?

Comment: How do you construct the `resp` ?

Comment: This issue here isn't one of being pythonic, which is mostly a matter of style. Here, that warning is being issued because you are fundamentally doing something that is inadvisable, using part of the non-public API. If you can live with that then this is the solution. If you want more advice, then you cannot "put aside the reason" you want to do this.

Comment: resp is a rpc response from a Juniper device. for Junos >14.2 it returns json, in other cases xml. Of course I could first test the Junos version, but if I could simply check the type it would make it much easier. 
Still it shouldn't matter how i construct this - the goal, out of pure curiosity, is to know how ho chech such "protected types".

Comment: You should be able to use `lxml.etree._Element`'s public subclass `ElementBase` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the language-design level, the "protected" nature of `_Element` means that the return type is an implementation detail. For instance, the next library version could suddenly return `_GreenElement` and `_RedElement`, because there is no "contract" about what the return type should be.

The pythonic way to deal with this is to "duck-type", i.e. check only for the methods/properties that you need for your task, without caring about the exact type of the object.

```
try:
    resp = json.loads(resp.text)
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Comment: That looks like a neat solution to me :) Thanks